# Inlcusion of compactly supported Sobolev Space in Closure of $C_0^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ in $W^{k,q}(\Omega)$

Tags: reference-request, compactness, sobolev-spaces

Denote by $W_0^{k, q}$ the closure of $C_0^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ in $W^{k,q}(\Omega)$ and by $W_c^{k, q}(\Omega)$ the set of functions from $W^{k, q}(\Omega)$ that have compact support in $\Omega$. I was able to show that
$$
W_c^{k, 2}(\Omega) \subset W_0^{k, 2}(\Omega)
$$
and now I wanted to ask if there is a proof for $W_c^{1, q}(\Omega) \subset W_0^{1, q}(\Omega)$.

I have looked in some books (Sobolev Spaces by Adams, PDE by Evans) but without success.

Comment: Assuming $\Omega$ here is an open set: if $u \in W^{k,q}_c(\Omega)$ has compact support in $\Omega$, you can extend it by 0 to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then look at $u_n = u \ast \psi_n$ for compactly supported mollifiers $\psi_n$.  Then $u_n \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and, by standard facts, $u_n \to u$ in $W^{k,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, hence also in $W^{k,q}(\Omega)$.  If you choose $\psi_n$ with small enough support, you can even have $u_n$ supported in $\Omega$.  Doesn't that settle it, or am I missing something?

Comment: That's pretty much how I did it for $k=2$

Comment: But I think the argument is valid for all $k$.  Is there some particular reason why you think it only works for $k=2$ and not otherwise?

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually not, I hoped someone would find a flaw but it seems fine so far...